# Entity wont delete from Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure, entity

when i try  to delete the entity Visual Studio keeps crashing on the line "serviceContext.DeleteObject(entity);"and saying "The context is not currently tracking the entity." Has anyone any ideas why and how to fix it?

```
    CloudTableQuery<ScheduleEntity> query = scheduleManNot.retrieveSchedule();

            //Checks every entry 
            foreach (ScheduleEntity entity in query)
            {
                comparison = System.DateTime.Compare(entity.eventTime, time);

                if (comparison <= 0)
                {
                    changeConfirmation = scheduleManNot.changeInstanceCount(entity.subscriptionID, entity.amount, entity.serviceName);

                    if (changeConfirmation == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Configuration Change failed");
                    }

                    if (changeConfirmation == true)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Configuration Change Succeeded");
                        Console.WriteLine(entity.serviceName + " had its instance count changed to " + entity.amount); 


                       serviceContext.AttachTo("schedule", entity, "*");
                       serviceContext.DeleteObject(entity);

                        //Submit the operation to the table service
                        serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are receiving the entity over a query, you do not need to attach the entity. 
Thus I think here attachto is not needed at all as you have stated in the comment. 
If you need to delete an unattached entity, you can first attach it and mark is as deleted.

Comment: i checked and "schedule" is the right dataset. To be honest i amnt exactly sure how AttachTo works, anywhere else i delete an Object i dont have to do it

Comment: Figured it out, i was creating 2 service contexts and using the wrong one. I moved the retrieve schedule into this class and got rid of a service and got rid of the other declaration and it works fine now